# A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'. in ionic cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

[image]

My SDK is updated but i seems again and again showing this error. When i run the ionic cordova build  android it seems giving me this error. I have also added the screenshot.

Also update the my NDK `android-sdk->ndk-bundle->toolchains`

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
    at
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because jCenter delete this package, the build is now dependent on the google repository，so make google() as your preferred.

```
     //Edit platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle
     repositories {
        google()
        maven {
              url “https://maven.google.com”
        }
        jcenter () 
     } 


    //And edit platforms / android / build.gradle
    buildscript {
       repositories {
        google()
        maven {
        url “https://maven.google.com”
        }
        jcenter ()
    }

    allprojects {
       repositories {
       google()
       maven {
         url “https://maven.google.com”
       } 
      jcenter ()
    }
```

Comment: I tried this one but given me the **No toolchain found in the ndk toolchains folder for ABI with prefix  : mips64p1-linux-android**. I have manually upload the NDK files From this url : https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/ But did not sovled this this error.